# Swift Metal CPU frame time unexpectedly reduced by half with no code changes?

Tags: swift, metal, frame-rate, metalkit

I'm building a project with MetalKit, and just the other night, my view was locked at 60fps and my frame times for the CPU and GPU were 16 and 8ms respectively.

Today, I was messing with my app some more, and I literally didn't touch a single part of my code that would improve frame times in any way, literally nothing even related to the GPU; yet, upon running my app, my view started rendering at **120fps** and my frame times were **halved.**

My iPad didn't receive a software update, and it's been plugged in 24/7. Does anyone have any idea what else could randomly cause this? The old 60fps was constant across weeks up until now. I'll accept the performance boost but I don't know where it came from...

Comment: My bet is on ProMotion being disabled for some reason, such as low power mode.